# Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 16.04.01 - Lenovo z50-70

Tags: drivers, 16.04, bluetooth

I have been trying to make bluetooth work on my Lenovo Z50-70 for a few days now on Ubuntu 16.04.01 but i have had no luck at all.
It seems like it works the first time i boot after a fresh install, but then stops working after a reboot?

My wifi is working fine.

Here's the output of `lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep firmware`

> Bus 001Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
>   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
>   bluetooth             520192  9 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel 
>   [   22.136977] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2

Comment: Lenovo G510 here, having problems with the 105b:e065 Bluetooth as well. It is detected, but does not search devices and can't be visible.
After extracting the drivers using hex2ccd and putting it to: `brcm/BCM.hcd ` makes the Bluetooth to be not found at all.